# Why is this nullref error displayed as such and what does it means?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, migradoc

I'm sorry if this has already been answered, but for the love of me I can't find any way to formulate the problem.

I'm going through a Unity crash log, in which I found the only nullref there is, obviously the source of the issue.

However the log isn't giving me an explicit line in my code, only some lacunar information about the context in which the exception has been caught.

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at Virtuallyz.SNCF_RAT.Formation.PdfSaver.GenerateRatTable ([ ... params ... ]) [0x00000] in 
<e05b58e6c1f74067973c3e9105184851>:0
```

I don't understand the format. Can someone explain what's displayed after the method signature ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Is the method `Virtuallyz.SNCF_RAT.Formation.PdfSaver.GenerateRatTable()` a C# method from your code?

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride Yes it is

Comment: I'm not sure about this stacktrace format either, but it looks like a memory address of the code that failed and some sort of hash. It's weird that the hex address is 0 which makes me believe it's not valid anyway. Have you tried compiling and running your program with debug symbols to see if that improves the stacktrace? It should give proper line numbers then.

Comment: builds dont normally include line numbers, as well, they are compiled and usually in release mode which strips that information - as it should

Comment: Ok thanks, A colleague tested on another machine than mine. I got the exact line of the error on my machine, with my environment the log gave me the exact line. So you were probably right about the symbols I guess. Thank you !